# Designing Uneven Tables In HTML

Tags: html

I would like to create a table that has 3 columns. In the first column will be 1 row

```
country     group     description

name        sub1      details
            sub2      details
            sub3      details
```

Now, I've come up with one solution that is almost there:

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Country</th>
      <th>Group</th>
      <th>Description</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>name</td>
      <td>sub1</td>
      <td>details</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>sub2</td>
      <td>details</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>sub3</td>
      <td>details</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

The problem with this approach is that now the row doesn't encapsulate the data anymore. It's split and I cannot easily search or group by knowing the row anymore.

I've tried to achieve a similar thing but I've yet to achieve it. If I use rowspan on the first column, i need to create other `<tr>` to be able to see the effect.

Comment: I think (may be wrong) there is an attribute call `rowspan` where you can span rows

Comment: It's not exactly clear what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't make it clear.  I was trying to put everything in a single `<tr>` that would encapsulate all of the subs and details.  I don't believe that is possible sense it appears they have to be physically different `<tr>` to expand into.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using "rowspan" in the `<td>` for "name", and remove the other `<td>`'s in successive rows:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Country</th>
      <th>Group</th>
      <th>Description</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="3">name</td>
      <td>sub1</td>
      <td>details</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>sub2</td>
      <td>details</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>sub3</td>
      <td>details</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Ok, I think I was wrong in my understanding of rowspan. They have to be actually separate rows then right? I was trying to put everything in a single `<tr>` that would encapsulate all of the subs and details. I don't think that is possible so I will probably end up doing it this way. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> now the row doesn't encapsulate the data anymore. It's split and I
>   cannot easily search or group by knowing the row anymore.

But you can use as many tbody's as needed to group (encapsulate?) your data:

```html
<table border>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Country</th>
      <th>Group</th>
      <th>Description</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan=3>name</td>
      <td>sub1</td>
      <td>details</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>sub2</td>
      <td>details</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>sub3</td>
      <td>details</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>

  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan=3>name B</td>
      <td>sub1.B</td>
      <td>details.B</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>sub2.B</td>
      <td>details.B</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>sub3.B</td>
      <td>details.B</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```